# How do I get an item with subelements from an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I have a class for quotes that contains an array full of quotes. The code below shows two. Each quote has an author, attribution, and Bools for `hasSeen` and `hasSaved`.

I want to show one random quote at a time. When the user refreshes the screen, they get another quote. When I put `.randomElement()!` on the array and print the results, I get `appName.Quote`.

Is there a way to access a random quote from this array? I want to be able to show the text and attribution to the end user.

```
var quotes:[Quote] = [
    Quote(
        quoteText: "The only way to make sense out of change is to plunge into it, move with it, and join the dance.",
        quoteAttribution: "Alan Watts",
        hasSeen: false,
        hasSaved: false),
    Quote(
        quoteText: "Luck is what happens when preparation meets opportunity.",
        quoteAttribution: "Seneca",
        hasSeen: false,
        hasSaved: false)
]
```

Comment: FYI - you should not be putting all of that data in code. Store it in a file or database and load what you need at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend swift's Array to have this feature:

```
extension Array {
    func randomItem() -> Element? {
        if isEmpty { return nil }
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        return self[index]
    }
}
```

And you access random Quote like this:

```
let quote = quotes.randomItem()
```

On a side note, since you are dealing with fixed/staitc content/structure, consider using [tuple](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/tuple-type) for storing Quote

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: No, do not consider using a tuple. A struct for `Quote` is the correct approach, not a tuple.